# When i run my appium code during run time i am getting this error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError"?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, appium

I have written a code to launch my app and click on the element, the app is launching but after launching when it is trying to click, I am getting an error which I am not able to understand why.

Error

> Feb 19, 2019 2:54:42 PM io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1 lambda$0
>   INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/cglib/proxy/MethodInterceptor
>       at pageobjects.HomePage.(HomePage.java:12)
>       at pages.SignUp.main(SignUp.java:22)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodInterceptor
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>       ... 2 more

This is the class code

```
package pages;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement;
import page_objects.Home_page;

public class SignUp extends MobileCap 
{

public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver = Capabilities();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    Home_page h = new Home_page(driver);
    h.SignUp.click();

}
}
```

Comment: can you add code showing the class where you are getting this error?

Comment: @JitendraJogeshwar i have updated the class code

Comment: @manoj: Can you check if you have all dependent jars extracted and put in the right dependency management system. To me, looks like something is missing from the stacktrace.

Comment: @manoj Its seems that code and stack trace is different. Can you add code for HomePage class which is shown int the stack trance?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look your dev environment. I suffered same issue when the maven project setting include testng library only test scope